# AJAX POST, why is data sent over URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I make an Ajax Post and get the following error: 
**414 Request-URI Too Large**

Why is the data still sent over the URL and not only in the body?
In Chrome is see param1 data in the request URL, query string parameters and in request payload, how to remove it from the URL?

```
routes = JSON.stringify(routes);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/s",
            data: {
              param1: routes
            },
            success: function(data) {
              $('div.home-products').html(
                data);
            }
          });
```

This is the full routes object after stringify:

```
{"0":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":-19.9245,"lng":-43.93520000000001}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":54},"1":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":52.52,"lng":13.404999999999973}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":53},"2":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":44.7866,"lng":20.44889999999998}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":52},"3":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":37.9838,"lng":23.727499999999964}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":51},"4":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":40.8518,"lng":14.268100000000004}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":50},"5":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":48.0527,"lng":12.224500000000035}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":49},"6":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":48.8566,"lng":2.3522199999999884}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":48},"7":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":51.0504,"lng":13.737300000000005}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":47},"8":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":49.7764,"lng":12.091699999999946}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":46},"9":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":49.7764,"lng":12.091699999999946}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":44}}
```

This the Chrome network

**Request URL:** http://127.0.0.1:3000/en/s?param1=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A-19.9245%2C%22lng%22%3A-43.93520000000001%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A54%7D%2C%221%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A52.52%2C%22lng%22%3A13.404999999999973%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A53%7D%2C%222%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A44.7866%2C%22lng%22%3A20.44889999999998%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A52%7D%2C%223%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A37.9838%2C%22lng%22%3A23.727499999999964%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A51%7D%2C%224%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.8518%2C%22lng%22%3A14.268100000000004%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A50%7D%2C%225%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A48.0527%2C%22lng%22%3A12.224500000000035%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A49%7D%2C%226%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A48.8566%2C%22lng%22%3A2.3522199999999884%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A48%7D%2C%227%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A51.0504%2C%22lng%22%3A13.737300000000005%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A47%7D%2C%228%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A49.7764%2C%22lng%22%3A12.091699999999946%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A46%7D%2C%229%22%3A%7B%22result_api%22%3A%7B%22geocoded_waypoints%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%2C%22routes%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22status%22%3A%22ZERO_RESULTS%22%2C%22request%22%3A%7B%22origin%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A49.7764%2C%22lng%22%3A12.091699999999946%7D%7D%2C%22destination%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%7B%22lat%22%3A40.7127753%2C%22lng%22%3A-74.0059728%7D%7D%2C%22travelMode%22%3A%22DRIVING%22%7D%7D%2C%22id%22%3A44%7D%7D&view=grid
**Request Method: POST
Status Code: 414 Request-URI Too Large
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade**
**Response Headersview source
Connection: close
Content-Length: 331
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 18:40:48 GMT
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.4/2017-03-30)**
**Request Headersview source
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4338
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:** _st_session=SkhkUk1HSHhSS1liRXVZbmZBZUcxcE1IZkhVcTNpYkFrWnNWbE5TaFY4b295c0RIVlJMQ09EbFVhQnJvWXA5OW5QeGY4dEhnREpUN09rZUR3eDVOM1UyWWRxcUllN3E2azM2TE0zakttbnZENzRmRU5lWGRHN0ZaNFh6c1MrVzBZd1R1Q1lDeGNGb1Z5M0ZGZ1hncTlUZG9kMnFHdUFuNXg4R01pckR3dHFhYzhtb0l2VW0rWWZwUVV2UGJ1bXQrWE1OVGhDREpTellKV3VKaDVEQnZNQ0FmYkRmL3BoZjVwUG8vNmRucnpuOG9jOUhXUnpWS2dCeC9NUWx0Y2ZNcmtuMDludWhybmxBUTAxNjhPNi95U2c9PS0tV2VqeWNBV3k1d1VrNDBnMEwxa0Z6Zz09--76684486bfaa221829f7d6c7f99d1833550ef865
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/s?view=grid
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token: rlyweDRRbVWVz+TC3MW+roDh2N9WFoAfAPT5oiC+k6LfCgMx4N4zbpfRP98UUT9H2y55Fzco9pI3MQjkuqkPng==
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
**Query String Parametersview source view URL encoded**
param1: {"0":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":-19.9245,"lng":-43.93520000000001}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":54},"1":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":52.52,"lng":13.404999999999973}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":53},"2":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":44.7866,"lng":20.44889999999998}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":52},"3":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":37.9838,"lng":23.727499999999964}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":51},"4":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":40.8518,"lng":14.268100000000004}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":50},"5":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":48.0527,"lng":12.224500000000035}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":49},"6":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":48.8566,"lng":2.3522199999999884}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":48},"7":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":51.0504,"lng":13.737300000000005}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":47},"8":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":49.7764,"lng":12.091699999999946}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":46},"9":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":49.7764,"lng":12.091699999999946}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":44}}
view: grid
**Form Dataview source view URL encoded**
param1: {"0":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":-19.9245,"lng":-43.93520000000001}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":54},"1":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":52.52,"lng":13.404999999999973}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":53},"2":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":44.7866,"lng":20.44889999999998}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":52},"3":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":37.9838,"lng":23.727499999999964}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":51},"4":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":40.8518,"lng":14.268100000000004}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":50},"5":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":48.0527,"lng":12.224500000000035}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":49},"6":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":48.8566,"lng":2.3522199999999884}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":48},"7":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":51.0504,"lng":13.737300000000005}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":47},"8":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":49.7764,"lng":12.091699999999946}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":46},"9":{"result_api":{"geocoded_waypoints":[{},{}],"routes":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS","request":{"origin":{"location":{"lat":49.7764,"lng":12.091699999999946}},"destination":{"location":{"lat":40.7127753,"lng":-74.0059728}},"travelMode":"DRIVING"}},"id":44}}
view: grid

Comment: May be an obvious question, but... What is the value of `window.location.href` when this executes?  That is, what's the URL you're currently on (including any query string arguments) when this code is run?

Comment: Shall I take it that `window.location.href` has a lot of parameters already attached to it, and you were hoping they'd be stripped off automatically?

Comment: so you want the get variables using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you ping `window.location.href`?

Comment: At the time of execution, 'window.location.href'  is just "http://127.0.0.1:3000/s?view=grid"

Comment: I don't want to use any get variables using javascript, I just want to send data via post to a controller with the current url route.

Comment: @charly1212 can u share full routes object ?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you're just mis-interpreting what you are seeing.

Comment: I added the chrome output of the request, still I have no idea why it also gets sent via url

Comment: and I changed to a static url, doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the missing `contentType: "json",` option.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but see if this helps:

```
url: window.location.href.replace(/\?.*$/, ''),
```

You definitely don't need to be passing along the get parameters that are in your href value, and this will strip them off. Perhaps the presence of any get parameters, even if it's just `view-grid` causes `ajax` to send your POST parameters as query parameters as well.

Comment: your are right I don't want to pass it along the get parameters, but this still doesn't strip them off, I will try to remove the view=grid and see how it works

Comment: url is now "http://127.0.0.1:3000/s" but it still sends it also as get parameters :/